# Kendo UI for MVC: Rendering a Grid in a PanelBar

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

MVC 4. When I place a `Grid` inside a Kendo UI PanelBar it does not work as expected. The View ends up not putting the `Grid` in the `Content()`, but rather itself into the panel over and over again `recursively` forever.

```
@(Html.Kendo().PanelBar()
  .Name("IntroPanelBar")
  .Items(items =>
      {
          items.Add()
               .Text("papering Reports")
               .Selected(true)
               .Expanded(true)
               .Content(() => Html.RenderAction("Grid"));
```

To see if it's my code, I put the Grid outside of the PanelBar and everything renders fine with the gird outside the PanelBar :

```
@{
   Html.RenderAction("Grid");
}

@(Html.Kendo().PanelBar()
  .Name("IntroPanelBar")
  .Items(items =>
      {
          items.Add()
               .Text("papering Reports")
               .Selected(true)
               .Expanded(true)
               .Content("PLAIN TEXT");
```

Comment: Does your "Grid" action need to be it's own action on the controller? Are you using it elsewhere or is it only used here in this panel? If it is only used in this panel you might consider putting the grid view code directly into this view. My guess right now is that when you are including the grid within the Panel's content you need to invoke .ToClientTemplate() on the grid, and your view is not doing that.

Comment: THe grid is used in other places, so is a partial view in this case. I found the solution though. I should use '.Content(Html.Action("Grid").ToHtmlString());' instead of '.Content(() => Html.RenderAction("Grid")); '

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to use the **MVCHtmlString** output of the Action instead:

```
@(Html.Kendo().TabStrip()
  .Name("tabstrip")
  .Items(tabstrip =>
      {
          tabstrip.Add().Text("papering")
                  .Selected(true)
                  .Content(Html.Action("Grid").ToHtmlString());   <---
```

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an older question but it popped up when I searched a similar problem. It could be solved by using the [Razor helper function](http://www.asp.net/web-pages/tutorials/working-with-pages/creating-and-using-a-helper-in-an-aspnet-web-pages-site). My example shows a Panel with a tab strip that contains a grid.

```
    <div id="panel">
    @(Html.Kendo().PanelBar()
        .Name("panelbar")
        .ExpandMode(PanelBarExpandMode.Single)
        .Items(panelbar =>
            {
                foreach (var a in Model)  {

                    panelbar.Add().Text(a.dom.fileName)
                        .Content(@<div id="tabs">
                            @RenderTabStrip(a)

                        </div>
                );

                }
            })
    )

    @helper RenderTabStrip(DominguezReport.WebInterface.Models.accModelTest a)
{
    @(Html.Kendo().TabStrip()
        .Name("tabs" +a.dom.recordID)
        .Items(tabstrip =>
        {
            tabstrip.Add()
                .Text("Status")
                .Content(@<div>@RenderStatusGrid(a)</div>);

            tabstrip.Add()
                .Text("Errors")
                .Content(@<div>@RenderErrorGrid(a)</div>);
        })
    );
}

     @helper RenderStatusGrid(DominguezReport.WebInterface.Models.accModelTest a)
{
    @(Html.Kendo().Grid(a.drs)
    .Name("Status")
    .Columns(columns=>
                    {
                        columns.Bound(c => c.currentStatus);
                        columns.Bound(c => c.updateTime);
                    })
                    .Scrollable()
      )
}
    @helper RenderErrorGrid(DominguezReport.WebInterface.Models.accModelTest a)
{
    @(Html.Kendo().Grid(a.dre)
    .Name("Errors")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(c => c.errorType);
        columns.Bound(c => c.errorDetail);
        columns.Bound(c => c.updateTime);
    })
    .Scrollable()
)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I tried the below code and it worked. Enclose your grid code in `<div>` tag in the Content part of PanelBar.

```
@(Html.Kendo().PanelBar()
.Name("panelbar")
.ExpandMode(PanelBarExpandMode.Single)
.Items(panelbar => 
    { 
             panelbar.Add().Text("Devices")
            .Expanded(true)
            .Content(@<div>@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
            ...grid code here
             </div>
            );
            })
            )
```